# Using EEPROM for transceiver data communication in Tx and Rx mode?

Tags: microcontroller, eeprom, transceiver

I am planning to use EEPROM (ST-M95640-DF) in between Transceiver IC (ST-S2LP) and the MCU (STM32L152RE). I would put program commands in a read-only section of the EEPROM to be accessed easily.
Now my question is it advisable to use EEPROM to write data that transceiver IC has received and transfer it to MCU via SPI with a possible C language code? Will the write-time of EEPROM be a problem here for me? The data rate would be around 300 kbps and the clock would be operating at 25 MHz.

Comment: That would depend on which tranceiver, which MCU, and which EEPROM, which you don't say. What would putting the EEPROM achieve here anyway? How would the tranceiver be able to write the EEPROM all by itself, and how would it coordinate the EEPROM access with the MCU?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I have added the required details to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The tranceiver is a SPI slave like the EEPROM. They cannot communicate themselves between each other. They both need the MCU to be the master, so all data must go via MCU anyway.

Comment: Can one then ask EEPROM via MCU to send specific data to the transceiver? Or it will have to be first passed on to MCU and then to the transceiver IC?

Comment: No, because EEPROM can't work alone, and neither the tranceiver. And they need the MCU to provide bit clock. And even if you do set the chips on the same SPI bus with separate chip selects, the problem is that EEPROM data output is connected to tranceiver data output. Communication must go via MCU in any case.